# Formula to values once data is entered in another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have columns with formula wherein the result will pop out once a data is entered in column O. Meaning at first these formulas look blank and Column O is like the trigger for the other data to pop out (like an isblank formula). Is there a way to make the formulas of other columns become values once column O is entered populated/once they pop out?

Comment: in VBA (since you tagged your question with it): `myRange.Value = myRange.Value` where `myRange` is the range you want to convert from formulas to values

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I’m new to vba and would appreciate if you expand on your answer. For example column A has a formula but remains blank until a data is entered in column O. Is there a way for column A to become a value once I enter data in column O, and the result popped out in column A?

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is:

- Column A appears blank if there's no data in the corresponding cells in column O
- Column A shows a result if there's data in the corresponding cells column O

This can be done without VBA.

If you want 12345 to show up in A1, use this formula:

=IF(ISBLANK(O1),"",123)

If you want "Hello World" to show up in A1, use this formula:

=IF(ISBLANK(O1),"","Hello World")

(replace 123 or Hello World with whatever you want it to say)

If you want the formula itself in column A to be removed, then you'll need VBA.

Comment: Thank you! But I already have the isblank formula in A. What I want to do is when I type in column O, after a data appears in column A, the data in A becomes a value. Formula to value in A after a data entry in O.